# Change element contents depending on current database record in Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

Please refer to the image below to have an idea of the look.

I have a database in ruby on rails named sauces.

The fields in the sauces table are as follows:

- id
- name
- description
- picture

This is my css:

```
#container{width:950px;height:800px;}
#title{this_is:irrelevant;}
#sauce_picture{bla bla}
#sauce_name{bla bla}
#sauce_splatter{background-image:url("someimage.png")}
```

HTML

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="container>
   <div id="title><h1>SAUCES</h1></div>
   <div id="sauce_picture><img src="somepic.png/></div>
   <div id="sauce_name><h2>Sauce 1</h2></div>
   <div id="sauce_splatter>
     <p>Sauce Description Goes Here</p> 
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Okay, the rails database table has 6 records with each field present. What I want to achieve is that say the page is loaded. I want the record to be at record number one, where the contents of`<img src="somepic.png/>` , `<h2>Sauce 1</h2>` , `<p>Sauce Description Goes Here</p>` are all retrieved from the database table because the count starts at one.

I do not know how to make it so that when the right arrow is pressed the id becomes two and the contents of the above change to what is present in record number 2 (id=2).

Lastly how would I do it so that, if the id=1 (i.e. first record, the left arrow becomes disabled as a link, and when the last record is present the right arrow becomes disabled. 
This would be achieved by changing the elements using JQuery, but how can I use Rails and Jquery together.

This way I wouldn't have to change any code if I add a new sauce in the database table in the future, after all thats the whole point of MCV.

Thanks

[image: The image]

Comment: there are tons of content slider plugins available to do what you want, why re-invent the wheeel?

Comment: its not as simple as a slider because for example I want the contents to change in one div i.e the container, not have a list of divs which slide through.

Comment: a content slider may fade in/out or slide up/down or sideways or do other effects. There are lots of them to choose from with controls already wired up and cross browser tesetd

Comment: perhaps you want an AJAX solution? Requet isn't very clear and there are content plugins for ajax also

Comment: your reccomendation will work for the most part. In the database table I will have a field to store an image for the splat (each sauce has a different) image, to have a background image for a div requires css. The JQuery sliders do not have an option for me to change the div background because all the li will be populated in the .html file in ruby code.

Comment: there are very simple solutions either with css or hooking into slider events that can handle that. It sounds like you need somone with more front end experince helping. It makes no difference what server language is generating the html...it's still html

Answer (score 0):

a possible solution, as long as your Sauces-Table doesn't have many entries, is to hand over an array like

```
@sauces = Sauce.all
```

your view could render one entry of the array by default and for updating the divs you need to code some JavaScript which keeps track of the actual selected entry and will update the divs with the attributes of the newly selected sauce.

For a larger table you can use AJAX to retrieve the selected sauce from the backend but you still need to update your content divs on the async call result via JavaScript.

you can also render a div for each sauce entry and hide all but the actual one to be displayed, upon pressing a button a hidden div with the selected sauce will be displayed and the other one will be set to invisble also via JavaScript

Comment: the sauce table currently has 6 entries (records). This is the whole point. In the future if a new sauce is added, I do not need to mess around with anything, I want it to be as simple as adding a new record in the database table and everything else is updated automatically